Why does Judaism SE have many questions compared to others?
Generalisation of : Why does Judaism.StackExchange have nearly triple as many questions as Islam.StackExchange?

What's up with how Judaism Stackexchange has 42,367 questions while Christianity SE has only 17,356 questions & Islam SE has only 15,577 questions and similar for Hinduism & Buddhism? I mean, what, many gentile Christians trying to convert you or Muslims or liberals who hate Israel? Lol.
Case 1. Based on Nobel prizes %age population %age assuming 8 billion people



+
A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1
Religion
Population
% population
Questions
% questions
Ratio (%Q/%P)
Pop/Ques


2









3
Christianity
2,496,000,000
31.20%
17,356
16.83%
54%
143,811.94


4
Judaism
16,000,000
0.20%
42,367
41.08%
20540%
377.65


5
Atheism
1,280,000,000
16.00%






6
Hinduism
1,208,000,000
15.10%
19,165
18.58%
123%
63,031.57


7
Buddhism
552,000,000
6.90%
8,670
8.41%
122%
63,667.82


8
Other
520,000,000
6.50%






9
Islam
1,928,000,000
24.10%
15,577
15.10%
63%
123,772.23


10









11
Total
8,000,000,000
100.00%
103,135
100.00%
100%
77,568.24



So 41% of questions from the 5 major religions are for Jews who make up only 0.2% of the population. That's a ratio of 20,540%. That's double the Nobel prize ratio 21.10% Nobels divided by 0.2% Jews =    10,550%. Or Population/Question ratio is 377.65, like 1 question for every 400 Jews.
Case 2. From Wikipedia page on Muslim population assuming everyone adheres the majority religion of the country and assuming 3x Jews in Israel based on the estimated Jews in the US eligible for Israeli citizenship under law of return and assuming you're Buddhist if you're not in a majority Christian, Jewish, Hindu or Muslim country.



+
A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1
Religion
Population
% population
Questions
% questions
Ratio (%Q/%P)
Pop/Ques


2









3
Christianity
2,541,280,296
33.49%
17,356
16.83%
50%
146,420.85


4
Judaism
25,274,712
0.33%
42,367
41.08%
12335%
596.57


5









6
Hinduism
1,400,583,150
18.46%
19,165
18.58%
101%
73,080.26


7
Buddhism/misc
1,869,250,943
24.63%
8,670
8.41%
34%
215,599.88


8









9
Islam
1,752,707,977
23.10%
15,577
15.10%
65%
112,518.97


10









11
Total
7,589,097,078
100.00%
103,135
100.00%
100%
73,584.11



So 41% of questions from the 5 major religions are for Jews who make up only 0.3% of the population. That's a ratio of 20,540%. That's now about the Nobel prize ratio 21.10% Nobels divided by 0.2% Jews = 10,550%. The Population/Question ratio is 596.57, like 1 question for every 600 Jews.

No idea, but no doubt in my mind it's in big part because of Talmud - our culture is Q&A.

One factor that should be accounted for is percentage of people from each religion in Anglo countries, which is where I think most SE members come from. In numbers Jews are still a minority, but it may change the percentages. As to why - this is merely based on things I've heard from people who have decided to explore Judaism - but I gather that in Christianity and Islam questions are often discouraged, which is not usually the case in Judaism.

Our entire history, our culture, our continuity as a people, is based on asking and answering questions. It’s in our DNA. Any Jew who didn’t ask questions ended up not knowing what to teach their children; and if their children didn’t ask questions either, they didn’t learn enough to continue practicing Judaism. The only Jews left are the ones who ask questions persistently, until they get a well-sourced and personally satisfactory answer. You can’t be a Jew and not ask questions.

I think it's mad that there are 377.65 - 596.57 Jews on earth, per question vs. 63,031.57 - 215,599.88 for all others!

What's the Meta policy on comparative religion meta?

I'm not sure that this question can be answered.

I don't know much about Christianity or Islam, so I'm not claiming any particular degree to which any of the following is unique to Judaism, but Judaism includes the following features that motivate people to share lots of questions and answers about it:

A vast, rich literature, developed over the course of millennia, with more being added every day.

The literature includes modes such as lore, law, poetry, ethics, and mysticism.

Large amounts of the literature are considered to be Divine in origin - either written by God, written by prophets in contact with God, or originated as an oral tradition by God.

Communities of adherents who pattern much to all of their lives on the laws and ethical teachings found in the tradition and literature. (And therefore comprise a complex living embodiment of the tradition.)

A core mandate for all members of the community to spend time learning and becoming expert in the literature, throughout all stages of life.

A tradition of weekly public reading of sections of the core text (five books of Moses), completing the text over the course of the year, driving communities and individuals to study and discuss the weekly section and commentaries and related texts.

A great deal of the legal literature consists of questions and answers. The Talmud is full of accounts of rabbis posing questions to each other to request information or rulings or to challenge each others' positions. Much of the development of legal concepts through the centuries came through precedents set in rabbinic respsonsa, in which formal questions posed to a rabbi and the responding rulings are published together.

One key annual ceremony - one of the most popular across the Jewish world - is conducted by families joining together at home, and features, in various ways, participants posing questions to each other. (This Stack Exchange community is named after a song containing one set of such questions.)


